# How to find the size of all partitions

Tags: command-line, partitioning

How can I find size the of all partitions in Ubuntu with a command that saves to `name.txt`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the size of all the partitions and save it to a file: you have to run this command:

```
df -h | grep /dev > name.txt
```

It will find the size of all the partitions including swap and save it to your file `name.txt`. where udev is nothing but the `swap`

or simply:

```
df -h > name.txt
```

If you want to get the size of all devices available to your computer and want to save in file then you can execute this command:

```
lsblk | awk '{print $1 "       \t    " $4}' > name.txt
```

<sub>It will save only the partition and the size</sub>

Comment: This will only show the size of the **mounted** partitions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lsblk` which prints partition information in a human friendly way, but can also change to use `KEY=VALUE` if you want to parse it.

Simply use

```
lsblk > name.txt
```

which will provide partition information to a file called `name.txt` in the current directory.

Example output of `lsblk` which is in `name.txt`:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0  97.7G  0 part 
├─sda2        8:2    0 134.1G  0 part 
├─sda3        8:3    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5        8:5    0    57G  0 part /
└─sda6        8:6    0   9.3G  0 part [SWAP]
zram0       251:0    0 239.1M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram1       251:1    0 239.1M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram2       251:2    0 239.1M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram3       251:3    0 239.1M  0 disk [SWAP]
```

---

If you want a more machine friendly output, use the following command instead:

```
lsblk -bP -o NAME,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT > parseable.txt
```

which might produce (in `parseable.txt`). Sizes are in bytes because of the `-b` option.

```
NAME="sda" SIZE="320072933376" MOUNTPOINT=""
NAME="sda1" SIZE="104854820864" MOUNTPOINT=""
NAME="sda2" SIZE="144030984192" MOUNTPOINT=""
NAME="sda3" SIZE="1024" MOUNTPOINT=""
NAME="sda5" SIZE="61183361024" MOUNTPOINT="/"
NAME="sda6" SIZE="9999220736" MOUNTPOINT="[SWAP]"
NAME="zram0" SIZE="250691584" MOUNTPOINT="[SWAP]"
NAME="zram1" SIZE="250691584" MOUNTPOINT="[SWAP]"
NAME="zram2" SIZE="250691584" MOUNTPOINT="[SWAP]"
NAME="zram3" SIZE="250691584" MOUNTPOINT="[SWAP]"
```

In the case above, a mountpoint of `""` indicates not mounted. You probably wont have as much `zram` as me (or maybe none at all).

Answer (score -1):

I usually use this command to see partition size and usage:

```
df -h
```

Comment: The OP also asked how to add that info into a file named `name.txt`.